# How to extract the contours in the border of image in OpenCV, C++

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, vector

Im try to extract the contours of an image using `findContours()` in OpenCV I can get the contour but it is not getting the border contours of image how can I get it

this is my code segment:

```
void main(  )
{
src = imread( "F:/academic/pro4/t/twst.png" );
 Mat samples(src.rows * src.cols, 3, CV_32F);
 for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
 for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
  for( int z = 0; z < 3; z++)
    samples.at<float>(y + x*src.rows, z) = src.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[z];    
int clusterCount = 7;
Mat labels;
int attempts = 10;
Mat centers;
kmeans(samples, clusterCount, labels,   TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER|CV_TERMCRIT_EPS, 10000, 0.0001), attempts, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS  , centers );
Mat new_image( src.size(), src.type() );
for( int y = 0; y < src.rows; y++ )
for( int x = 0; x < src.cols; x++ )
{ 
  int cluster_idx = labels.at<int>(y + x*src.rows,0);
  new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[0] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 0);
  new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[1] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 1);
  new_image.at<Vec3b>(y,x)[2] = centers.at<float>(cluster_idx, 2);
}
 cv::erode(new_image,new_image,cv::Mat());
 cv::dilate(new_image,new_image,cv::Mat());
 imshow( "clustered image", new_image );
    char filename[80];
    sprintf(filename,"F:/academic/pro4/t/seg.png");
    imwrite(filename, new_image);
cvtColor( new_image, src_grays, CV_BGR2GRAY );
createTrackbar( " Canny thresh:", "Source", &threshs, max_threshs, thresh_callbacks );
thresh_callbacks( 0, 0 );
waitKey( 0 );
```

}

```
void thresh_callbacks(int, void* )
{
Mat canny_output;
vector<vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
cv::erode(src_grays,src_grays,cv::Mat());
cv::dilate(src_grays,src_grays,cv::Mat());
blur( src_grays, src_grays, Size(3,3) );
src_grays.convertTo(drawss, CV_8U);
imshow("AfterCluster", drawss);
Canny( src_grays, detected_edges, lowThreshold, lowThreshold*ratio, kernel_size );
vector<Point> pnts;
findNonZero(detected_edges, pnts);
fout<<pnts.size();
cout << "Total number of points: " << pnts.size() << endl;
for(size_t i = 0; i < pnts.size(); ++i){
cout << pnts[i] << endl;
fout<<"pnts"<<pnts[i];}
dst = Scalar::all(0);
src_grays.copyTo( dst, detected_edges); 
imshow( window_name, dst );

/// Find contours
Mat extended(detected_edges.size()+Size(2,2), detected_edges.type());
Mat markers = extended(Rect(1, 1, detected_edges.cols, detected_edges.rows));
findContours( detected_edges, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );

 for (vector<vector<Point> >::iterator it = contours.begin(); it!=contours.end(); )
{
if (it->size()<contour_length_threshold)
    it=contours.erase(it);
else
    ++it;
 }
 vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly( contours.size() );
 for(int i= 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
 {approxPolyDP( Mat(contours[i]), contours_poly[i], 3, true );
  if ( hierarchy[i][3] != -1 ) {
        // random colour
        Scalar colour( (rand()&255), (rand()&255), (rand()&255) );

    }

  for(int j= 0; j < contours[i].size();j++) // run until j < contours[i].size();
   { 
     int a= contours[i][j].x  ; 
     int b =contours[i][j].y ;
     if(j==1){
        b1  = src.at<Vec3b> (b, a).val[0];
        g1 = src.at<Vec3b> (b, a).val[1];
        r1 = src.at<Vec3b> (b, a).val[2];
    //  Vec3b pixel = src.at<Vec3b> (i, j);
        printf("%d,%d,%d\t",b1,g1,r1);
        int b2=b1;
        int g2=g1;
        int r2=r1;
     fout << b2<<','<<g2<<","<<r2<<'\t';

      }

    //printf("Point(%d, %d) %t", a, b);
    std::cout << contours[i][j] << std::endl;
     fout << contours[i][j];
}
//cout << " Area: " << contourArea(contours[i]) << endl;
//fout << " Area: " << contourArea(contours[i]) << endl;

fout<<endl;
fout<<endl;
printf ("%d \n", i);
printf ("%d \n", contours[i].size());
```

}

```
int a=contours.size();
Mat drawing_i = Mat::zeros( detected_edges.size(), CV_8UC3 );
for( int i = 0; i<contours.size(); i++ )
 {

   Scalar color = Scalar( rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255) );
   drawContours( drawing_i, contours, i, color, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point() );

 }
namedWindow( "Contours_i", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
   imshow( "Contours_i", drawing_i );
```

}
how can get contours of border and how can get closing objects contours

Comment: Posting a wall of code is not really neccesarry, is it? The problem you are stating seems more like a problem with your algorithm and not your code. Maybe try to Explain in detail what you are trying to achieve, what you have done so far, what works and what does not work. Add a picture for visualising your problem.

Comment: I'm basically trying to vectorizing so for that first clustering the image and using that clustered image  detecting the edges and using that edges trying to get contours. but the problem is its not getting the contours that on border of image